# scanning in specific word from a file

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have this file called pageRankList that contains url, number of outgoing links, page rank in that order.
if I want to get the pageRank of a given URL. How could I do this with fscanf or other functions?

```
url23 4 0.0405449
url31 3 0.0371111
url22 5 0.0300785
url34 4 0.0288782
url21 2 0.0247087
url11 3 0.0235192
url32 2 0.0227647
```

this is what I have so far but when I run it gives me a SEGV on unknown address error and I can't figure out why :(

```
static double getPageRank(char *url) {
    double pageRank = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("pageRankList.txt", "r");
    char str[1000];

    int counter = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp, " %98s", str) != EOF) {
        if (strcmp(url, str) == 0) {
            counter++;
            continue;
        }

        if (counter == 2) {
            pageRank = atof(str);
            printf("%f\n", pageRank);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return pageRank;
}
```

Comment: What debugging did you try? At least some increased outputting of intermediate values, no? Please make a [mre].

Comment: Well, you aren't checking if the file was opened successfully. Passing `NULL` to `fscanf` or `fclose` is usually a good way to cause a crash. As for the logic I don't see how counter would ever be 2, it'll only match the string for the first read of that line. Not sure why the `continue` is in there either. You might consider reading a line at a time and use `sscanf` to parse the the line and if the url matches return the rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf(fp, " %98s", str)`

This will stop reading when it hits a white space. It might be better to read all three things (url, number of outgoing links, page rank) at once. I would read a whole line at a time and then use `sscanf` on that:

```
static double getPageRank(const char* url)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("pageRankList.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) return -1;

    char str[1000];
    double pageRank = -1;

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp)) { // Read line
        int number;
        char line_url[100];
        // Try to parse line
        if (sscanf(str, "%99s %d %lf", line_url, &number, &pageRank) == 3) {
            if (strcmp(url, line_url) == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return pageRank;
}
```

*Note this works as long as `url` has no spaces.